# Dynamically declare framer motion html element type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I am trying to create a reusable component that will use a consistent transition throughout the app. In doing so, i've create a a div that uses framer-motion to animate. I'd like to be able to tell the component that its a div, span, etc.. via a prop.

Calling it like so:

```
<AnimatedEl el={'div'}>
    ...
</AnimatedEl>
```

```
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion'

interface AnimatedDivProps {
  el: string
  children: React.ReactNode
  className?: string
}

const AnimatedDiv = ({ el, className, children }: AnimatedDivProps) => {
  const transition = {
    duration: 0.8,
    ease: [0.43, 0.13, 0.23, 0.96],
  }
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <motion[el]
        className={className}
        initial='exit'
        animate='enter'
        exit='exit'
        variants={{
          exit: { y: 100, opacity: 0, transition },
          enter: { y: 0, opacity: 1, transition: { delay: 0.2, ...transition } },
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </motion[el]>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}

export default AnimatedDiv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic framer motion elements by creating a new component that is assigned to the `motion` function, with the element type passed in. Then use that new component in place of `motion[el]`.

so inside `AnimatedDiv` add:

```
const DynamicMotionComponent = motion(el);
```

then in the return statement use it like this:

```
<DynamicMotionComponent
  className={className}
  initial='exit'
  animate='enter'
  exit='exit'
  variants={{
    exit: { y: 100, opacity: 0, transition },
    enter: { y: 0, opacity: 1, transition: { delay: 0.2, ...transition } },
  }}
>
  {children}
</DynamicMotionComponent>
```

If you log the typeof `motion` and the typeof `motion.div`, you can see motion isn't an object but a callable function.

```
console.log(typeof motion) // => function
```

where as

```
console.log(typeof motion.div) // => object
```

---

Here's a different example of a wrapper component with a similar concept that creates motion elements based off of the child components. It fades in, animates y values and staggers children when the element is in view, the children could be a set of divs, svg's etc... it modifies the className prop of the child react component and applies the Framer Motion variants prop, here's how I achieved it:

```
import {
  Children,
  cloneElement,
  isValidElement,
  ReactChild,
  ReactFragment,
  ReactNode,
  ReactPortal,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
} from "react";
import {
  motion,
  useAnimationControls,
  useInView,
  Variants,
} from "framer-motion";
import CONSTANTS from "@/lib/constants";
import styles from "@/styles/components/motionFadeAndStaggerChildrenWhenInView/motionFadeAndStaggerChildrenWhenInView.module.scss";

interface MotionFadeAndStaggerChildrenWhenInView {
  childClassName?: string;
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  variants?: Variants;
}

type Child = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal;

const parentVariants = {
  fadeInAndStagger: {
    transition: {
      delayChildren: 0.3,
      ease: CONSTANTS.swing,
      staggerChildren: 0.2,
    },
  },
  initial: {
    transition: {
      ease: CONSTANTS.swing,
      staggerChildren: 0.05,
      staggerDirection: -1,
    },
  },
};

const childVariants = {
  fadeInAndStagger: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      ease: CONSTANTS.swing,
      y: { stiffness: 1000, velocity: -100 },
    },
    y: 0,
  },
  initial: {
    opacity: 0,
    transition: {
      ease: CONSTANTS.swing,
      y: { stiffness: 1000 },
    },
    y: 50,
  },
};

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-redeclare -- intentionally naming the variable the same as the type
const MotionFadeAndStaggerChildrenWhenInView = ({
  childClassName,
  children,
  className,
  variants = childVariants,
}: MotionFadeAndStaggerChildrenWhenInView) => {
  const childrenArray = Children.toArray(children);

  const childClassNames =
    childClassName !== undefined
      ? `${childClassName} ${styles.fadeAndStaggerChild}`
      : styles.fadeAndStaggerChild;

  const controls = useAnimationControls();
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const isInView = useInView(ref, { once: true });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInView) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
      controls.start("fadeInAndStagger");
    }
  }, [controls, isInView]);

  return (
    <motion.div
      ref={ref}
      animate={controls}
      className={
        className
          ? `${styles.fadeAndStaggerParent} ${className}`
          : styles.fadeAndStaggerParent
      }
      initial="initial"
      variants={parentVariants}
    >
      {Children.map(childrenArray, (child: Child) => {
        if (!isValidElement(child)) return null;

        if (isValidElement(child)) {
          const propsClassNames: string =
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
            Object.hasOwn(child.props, "className") === true
              ? // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
                (child.props.className as string)
              : "";

          const DynamicMotionComponent = motion(child.type);

          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
          return cloneElement(<DynamicMotionComponent />, {
            ...child.props,
            className: propsClassNames
              ? `${childClassNames} ${propsClassNames}`
              : childClassNames,
            variants,
          });
        }

        return null;
      })}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default MotionFadeAndStaggerChildrenWhenInView;
```